# Django redirection

Tags: django

I have a basic splash page, and I am trying to redirect all urls to the splash EXCEPT for the thank you page (which is linked to after the email form is submitted).

How do I make it such that all my urls will redirect to the splash page with the exception of this one page? Currently, ALL of my urls are re-directing, even the exception. Here is my code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^thanks/$', 'thanks'),
    (r'^', 'index_redirect'),
```

Thank you.

Comment: Two things to check: (1) have you restarted your application since your latest changes? (2) Are you testing http://url/thanks/ and not http://url/thanks ?

Comment: Ha, the URL distinction didn't come through clearly. I meant to distinguish between the thanks URL with and without the trailing slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django 1.3 you can use the redirect_to along with a pattern that matches everything.

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^thanks/$', 'thanks'),
    (r'^.*$', redirect_to, {'url': '/'}),
)
```

WARNING: this WILL match your static resources and images etc.